# How to use Gimp Scripts?

Tags: scripts, gimp

I am interesting in using this gimp [scripts](http://registry.gimp.org/node/28613) 
When I threw them in my gimp script folder and started gimp version 2.8.10 I could not find any of this filters, So I have a question where can I find installed scripts in gimp ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be *plug-ins* rather than scripts - if so, they need to go into your gimp plug-ins directory e.g.

```
unzip ~/Downloads/gimp_instagram_effects.zip -d ~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/
```

After that, they should be accessible via an `Instagram` filter group under the `Filters` menu.